# JavaScript: Creating an array to sort x number of names and print

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm unsure as to why this basic code is not functioning.

```
var name = new Array(10);
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    name[i] = prompt("Add names:", "");
    name.sort();
}

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    document.write(name[i] + "<br/>");
}
```

Comment: Move the `.sort()` out of the first for loop.

Comment: I tried removing it entirely. I get a bunch of commas and the word undefined.(the javacript prompt box is working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer to your second question.
So you don't have to define the size of the array but you would still want to know before how many times you want to execute the loop. 
Using a button would be okay as you can make a boolean var become false and stop the execution when the button is clicked. 
However in this situation clicking the button isn't an option because you keep getting prompts.

```
    var input = [];

    var numberOfNames=prompt("How many names would u like to sort");

    for(i=0;i<numberOfNames;i++){
    input[i] = prompt("Add names:", "");
    }
    input.sort();
    for(i=0;i<numberOfNames;i++){
    document.write(input[i] + "<br/>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to have a global variable called `name`. It conflicts with `window.name` and anything you set there is automatically converted into a string. Just change your variable name with something else, say `myName` and it works fine. Oh, and yes, move the `sort()` out of the loop.

Comment: Thankyou!! That makes sense. (it also works). Where would be the most appropriate place to put the .sort()? Can it go inside the second loop?

Answer (score 0):

it has to be outside the loops (not in the first nor in the second)
Because your loop is executed 10 times. So you dont want to sort 10 times.
Once you have all the values input in the name array.
THEN sort them.

```
    var name = new Array(10);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    name[i] = prompt("Add names:", "");
    }
    name.sort();
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    document.write(name[i] + "<br/>");
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou! It'll take me a while to understand the logic of array - I'm trying though. To take this example further, how could I have the array be an undefined amount? I'd need to use something else other than a prompt? I'd need a way of exiting the loop. Linke a html button maybe?

Comment: You cant click on a button if you keep having prompts.
But you can ask  the user how many names he wants to sort.